# How best translate 真的要 in to english

Tags: translation

I got the following sentence from Chinese pod: 
对不起，我今天真的要扫你的兴了，我不能去。
The translation provided goes like this:
Sorry, today I'm going to take the wind from your sails, I can't go.

Though I feel a little bit uncomfortable with it, wouldn't it be better to translate these three Hanzi with:

*really have to?!*

Comment: You already got it.

Comment: If you just wanna translate these 3 words, then you already got it.
But if sentence above "对不起，我今天真的要扫你的兴了，我不能去。" then it has many ways to do that.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can use 'for real' as 真的要, as it have the meaning for really or actually.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, I'm really going to turn you down today. I can't go.

It's a emphasis that the person saying is serious, it's not a joke.

Answer (score 2):

I would have thought "真的要" means "really have to/want/will" but I just Googled it.  Most of the uses I found could translate 要 as must or want to or as indicating a future action.  But in many of them you could just as well take the whole phrase 真的要 to mean "really."  And on some web pages it really does just mean "really," like

http://game.163.com/15/0211/10/AI5QNQUN00314OSE.html

The example seems to me ambiguous between "I really must," and "I'm really going to" and just "really."  It depends on whether you take 真的 as one phrase modifying 要扫你的兴了, or take 真的要 as modifying 扫你的兴了.  It looks to me like both are possible.

Answer (score 1):

真的: really

要: here means have to (since it's short of apologetic, not just the intention of further action(will))

So the translation would be something like:

> Sorry. I really have to let you down. I can't go.

Then let's brush it up with a touch of the emotion which might had been left out from the translation. It would be something like:

> Sorry. I'd (really) have to let you down. I can't go.

Answer (score 1):

really want to do something :)

e.g. I really want to kiss you!